# How do you set the HOME path with SSH on Cygwin?

Tags: windows-server-2008, cygwin, openssh

I have a bunch of users that I'd like to set the default HOME directory for so that when they log into SSHD running on Cygwin on Windows Server 2008, they get set at a specific directory (C:\sandboxsites\$USER)

Any idea on how you can do this with Cygwin/SSHD?

I followed these instructions to setup SSHD on Windows http://lifehacker.com/205090/geek-to-live--set-up-a-personal-home-ssh-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set their home directory in `/etc/passwd` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/225764/1630171) to a somewhat similar question on Stack Overflow).